# Show that a multivariable function is bounded and she admits a global maximum

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)= \frac{|a + bx + cy|}{1+x^2+y^2}$
$(a,b,c) \in R^3$

I want to show that f is bounded on $R^2$ and that she admits a global maximum.

I tried  to use this theorem  :
For $S$ a compact of $R^n$, for $f : S \to R^n$ $f$ a continuous function on $S$ and $C^1$ then $f$ is bounded on $S$ and admits a global maximum on $S$

But its look wrong because i have to show that she is bounded on $R^2$ and not on $S$

Actually i can say that $f$ is continuous on $R^2$

Comment: It looks like the numerator grows linearly in $x$ and $y$, whereas the denominator grows quadratically. You could try showing that $f$ is sufficiently small outside some closed ball $B$ around the origin (say, less than $|a|$). Then apply your theorem to B and combine it with the upper bound over the complement.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my approach. You can write

$$\frac{|a+bx+cy|}{1+x^2+y^2} \le \frac{|a|+|bx|+|cy|} {1+x^2+y^2} \text{(triangle inequality)}$$
If each part of the sum is bounded, we can add them up to get the overall bound. So let’s look at each part.  The first part is straightforward. It relies on the fact that each summand in the denominator is positive so that the sum is greater than each summand alone (and the reciprocal of the sum is less than the reciprocal of each summand).
$$\frac{|a|} {1+x^2+y^2} \le \frac{|a|}{1}$$
The next two parts use the same argument. We’ll work just the $|bx|$ term. There are two cases.
For $|x| \ge 1$:
$$\frac{|bx|} {1+x^2+y^2} \le \frac{|bx^2|}{x^2}=|b|$$
For $|x|<1$:
$$\frac{|bx|}{1+x^2+y^2}<\frac{|b|}{1}$$
A similar argument for the third term let’s us conclude that
$$\frac{|cy|}{1+x^2+y^2}\le|c|$$
Adding the parts together, we find an upper bound as desired:
$$\frac{|a+bx+cy|}{1+x^2+y^2} \le |a|+|b|+|c|$$